# Is there a way to specify the area to shade for Google AreaChart?

Tags: google-visualization

By default, if I'm using a -1 direction for my Y-axis, Google AreaChart will shade the top half.

Is there a way to specify in the draw options for Google AreaChart shade the bottom half?

So for instance, my ticks on the y-axis are as follows: 1 is at the top, and 15 is at the bottom.

If there is a line running parallel to the X-axis with Y value 5, Google AreaChart will shade 1 - 5 on the Y-axis, but I am trying to shade 5 - 15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AreaCharts always shade in the direction of the axis baseline, so you can set the `vAxis.baseline` option to the minimum value of the y-axis:

```
vAxis: {
    direction: -1,
    baseline: 15
}
```